# Predator–prey theory

Tags: qiskit

We have a project where we are supposed to simulate the predator–prey theory in qiskit. Can anyone help or suggest of any ways to start from somewhere because we are kinda lost.
[image: the equations we found and we are apparently supposed to use are these]

Comment: This seems to be a homework. What did you do so far and where you get stuck?

Comment: It indeed is. We have already wrote small parts of code for other stuff like coin toss algorithm but nothing like this and we dont know where to start. Like how do we even start with this, we have no examples or anything and the documentation isn't that useful with this. @MartinVesely